# aligning a table cell and formatting

Tags: css, html

I've a html where i want a particular cell to be aligned to left. below is the code and fiddle link.

HTML:

```
 <section class="tr_chapter">
            <div class="chapter"><a name="HKWBV1_ORD_89"></a>
                <div class="toc">
                    <div class="toc-part">
                        <table class="toc-div">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <table class="toc-item-third-level">
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td></td>
                                                    <td class="toc-item-num-left"><span class="font-style-bold">Contents</span></td>
                                                    <td class="toc-title"></td>
                                                    <td class="toc-pg"><span class="font-style-italic">para.</span></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>4/0/1</td>                                                  <td class="toc-item-num-left">1.</td>
                                                    <td class="toc-title">Companies (O.4, r.2)</td>
                                                    <td class="toc-pg"><a href="4/2">4/2</a></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td></td>
                                                    <td class="toc-item-num-left">2.</td>
                                                    <td class="toc-title">Consolidation, etc., of causes or matters (O.4, r.9)</td>
                                                        <td class="toc-pg"><a href="4/9">4/9</a></td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>

</section>
```

I want the output as given in the below image. i.e. the number (4/0/1). please let me know how can i do it.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cvKEk/)

Thanks[image]

Comment: I see no difference between the image and the code (except to the points).0 Which cell exactly do you want to align left?

Comment: Please do a thorough google search about your doubts and then do a StackOverflow search. Your question has probably been answered several times.

Comment: And, any problems using `thead`?

Comment: Hi @ Damian Frizzi. i want 4/0/1 to align left

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the cell with the number 4/0/1 aligned left simply give `align="left"` to the parent td or add to it a class with `text-align:left;`

See: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tP6hk/1/)

Comment: Thanks for responding. This is not working. i tried it in fiddle. :-(

Comment: Your whole html is totally messed up. You're using a table inside a table what you shouldn't. I updated my answer with a jsfiddle containing a refactored simple html table for your needs.

Comment: Hi @Damian, in my new fiddle i've added the whole CSS that i have(sorry for that, as i didn't make this CSS, i received it from our customer). [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jCyjr/). please edit or update it and solve my problem. Thanks

Comment: The cell is correctly aligned left. I think your problem is that you have a margin-left on the class chapter. See: http://jsfiddle.net/jCyjr/1/

Comment: Can you please give me your email id, if you don't mind. i need to chat with you about this, i'm really messed up here please